# How to use "within" in R?

Tags: r

I've been struggling with finding a way to evaluate an R expression in an environment constructed from data. I have a dataframe:

```
    head(DATA1) 
    COD_CLI      ENDEUD_FINAL
    1 01002901 Mediana Empresa
    2 01002932 No Sobreendeudado
    3 04203409 No Sobreendeudado
    ...
```

and I try to complete another data (DATA2):

```
    head(DATA2) 
    COD_CLI_W      ENDEUD_FINAL
    1 01002190   
    2 01002913   
    3 04203401   
    ...
```

DATA2 is larger than DATA1, if the same COD_CLI/COD_CLI_W is in both datas, I take the second column of DATA1, if not I must evaluate another dataframe "wallet":

```
    > str(wallet)
    'data.frame':   81101 obs. of  8 variables:
    $ COD_CREDITO     : chr  "0040410166104" "00000363393"          "0060030164135" "004023854M" ...
    $ COD_CLI         : chr  "00402037" "00166750" "00178607" "40097700" ...
    $ TIPO_DE_CREDITO : chr  "12.-CONSUMO NO REVOLVENTE" "10.-MICROEMPRESA" "10.-MICROEMPRESA" "10.-MICROEMPRESA" ...
    $ SITUACION_SAFI  : chr  "CASTIGADO" "CASTIGADO" "CASTIGADO" "CASTIGADO" ...
    $ COD_TIP_PRESTAMO: chr  "0747" "0748" "0748" "0747" ...
    $ ATR_SOL         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    $ CAP_SOL         : num  313.37 3.16 1670.51 3010 2327.71 ...
    $ NUM_ENT         : num  3 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 4 2 ...
```

Now the code I run is:

```
    DATA2 <- within(DATA2,{
    CALIF_RCD <- ifelse(COD_CLI_W %in% DATA1$COD_CLI,DATA1$ENDEUD_FINAL[which(DATA1$COD_CLI %in% COD_CLI_W)],
    ifelse(wallet$TIPO_DE_CREDITO[which(wallet$COD_CLI %in% COD_CLI_W)[1]] == "08.-MEDIANA EMPRESA","Mediana Empresa",
    ifelse(wallet$NUM_ENT[which(wallet$COD_CLI %in% COD_CLI_W)[1]]<5,"No Sobreendeudado","Sobreendeudado")))
    }
    )
```

the output is wrong in most of the cases. I'm new to R and I would like to know how to code it in a properly manner. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: sounds like you could just `merge` instead of writing nested `ifelse`s

Comment: I tried to do that but I don't know the correct aproach. DATA2 contains all the information of DATA1 and is larger. I would evaluate the elements that are only in DATA2 but I don't know how to create this subset with "merge" or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

I took the first approach using "merge":

```
    DATA3 <- merge(DATA1, DATA2, by.x = "COD_CLI", by.y = "COD_CLI_W", all.y=TRUE)
    DATA3 <- DATA3[!complete.cases(DATA3),]
```

After that, I analysed the left outer side in DATA3:

```
    w = NULL
    for(i in 1:length(DATA3$ENDEUD_FINAL))
    {
       w = which(wallet$COD_CLI %in% DATA3$COD_CLI[i])[1]
       DATA3$ENDEUD_FINAL[i] <- ifelse(wallet$TIPO_DE_CREDITO[w] == "08.-MEDIANA EMPRESA","Mediana Empresa",
       ifelse(wallet$NUM_ENT[w]<5,"No Sobreendeudado","Sobreendeudado"
       ))
    }
```

and finally "rbind" DATA1 and DATA2:

```
       DATA2 <- rbind(DATA1, DATA3)
```